# Awaiting Moderation Message not showing up in WordPress 4.9.6

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm working on my comment-section.

I have a very basic custom `Comment_Walker`. But it doesn't show the "Awaiting Moderation" string after posting a comment.

Comments are posted successfully to the backend. I have ticked that comments have to be manually approved in the settings in the backend.
A comment shows in the comment section in the backend as "pending". But I won't get the message when posting the comment.

My Walker File *(very basic reduced to demonstrate)*

```
<?php
/** Custom Comment Walker Basic */

class Custom_Comment_Walker extends Walker_Comment {

    protected function html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args ) {

        $tag = ( $args['style'] === 'div' ) ? 'div' : 'li';
        ?>      
        <<?php echo $tag; ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class( $this->has_children ? 'has-children col-12 p-0' : 'p-0 col-12 list-unstyled' ); ?>>


        <div>
            <?php echo get_comment_text(); ?>
            <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                Awaiting Moderation
            <?php endif; ?>  
        </div>

        <?php
    }   
}
```

Accessing it via:

```
<div class="comment-list">
    <?php 
      wp_list_comments( array(
          'walker'        => new Custom_Comment_Walker()
      ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

I don't quite understand why the message wouldn't show up. Do I oversee something here? Using the latest WordPress 4.9.6 on a localhost. I did deactivate literally every plugin I've had active before posting here. I have also tested this with different accounts and roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution was to have the "Save my name, email, and website in this browser for the next time I comment." checkbox selected in order for the message to show up.

So you have to have the GDPR checkbox to be checked in order to have the comment and message appearing **before** approval.

Sorry for bothering.

Comment: I can see why not checking that box would cause this issue - seems like an oversight to me on WordPress's part. FWIW, I looked further into this and found [this ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43857).